# Transfer text file to table in R with some conditions on it

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have one text file like this

```
DOB
Name
Address


13-03-2003
ABC
xyz.

12-08-2004
dfs
1 infinite loop.
```

text goes till approx 300 lines. And sometimes Address data exceeds to two second line also i want to convert this text data to either cvs format which will have data like this

```
DOB, Name, Address
13-03-2003,ABC,xyz.
```

or at least in one data frame. I tried so many things, when i am giving read.table("file.txt",sep="\n") it makes everything in one column and i also tried first making headers by using 
`header <- read.table("file.txt",sep= "\n")` 
and then another `data <- read.table("file.txt",skip = 3, sep ="\n")` and then combining both but its not working out as my header vector has 3 and data vector has like 300 approx columns, its not working as required. Any help will be really helpful :)

Comment: It depends on how well you constructed the example. Is there always an empty line between entries?

Comment: @Shilpi Any attempts from your side?

Comment: a `dput` could be nice

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes it has always an empty line.

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you please elaborate. :)

Comment: Are addresses the only part that will possibly have more than one line? Are there ever missing names addresses or date-of-births?

Comment: If you have uneven number of address rows, it may be better to `grep` on the `date` rows (assuming no missing dob) after reading the dataset with `readLines`.  Use that as an index to separate into different columns.  I would suggest to provide few more lines as an example

Comment: If the address is always the last entry, and names and date-of-births are never missing without an na string, you can split on lines one and two and group the rest.

Comment: No its never missing data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
entries <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\n")) #separate entries by line breaks
entries <- entries[nchar(entries) > 0] #remove empty lines
as.data.frame(matrix(entries, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)) #assemble dataframe 
#          V1   V2               V3
#1        DOB Name          Address
#2 13-03-2003  ABC             xyz.
#3 12-08-2004  dfs 1 infinite loop.
```

**data**

```
text <-'DOB
Name
Address


13-03-2003
ABC
xyz.

12-08-2004
dfs
1 infinite loop.'
df <- read.table(text = text)
```

Comment: This fails with multiple column addresses as stated in the q. try `01-01-2000\nBob Smith\n1234 Main St\nSuite 400`

Comment: @PierreLafortune I agree, this answer assumes that each entry occupies one line and that there are no missing entries. Since the file only has 300 lines it might be possible to edit the critical cases manually. Else, your solution seems to be able to handle these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Two assumptions were made, 1 there will not be any blank names or date of births. By "blank" I do not mean "NA", "", or any other marker that the value was missing. Second assumption was that names and DOBs will only occupy one line each.

```
s1 <- gsub("^\n|\n$", "", strsplit(x, "\n\n+")[[1]])
stars <- gsub("\n", ", ", sub("\n", "*", sub("\n", "*", s1)))
mat <- t(as.data.frame(strsplit(stars, "\\*")))
dimnames(mat) <- c(NULL, NULL)
write.csv(mat,"filename.csv")
```

We start by splitting the text by the blank lines and eliminating any leading or trailing newline tokens. Then we replace the first and second "\n" symbols with stars. Next we split on those new star markers that we created to always have 3 elements for each row. We create a matrix with the values and transpose it for display. Then write the data to csv.

When opened with Notepad on a test file, I get:

```
"","V1","V2","V3"
"1","DOB","Name","Address"
"2","13-03-2003","ABC","xyz."
"3","12-08-2004","dfs","1 infinite loop"
"4","01-01-2000","Bob Smith","1234 Main St, Suite 400"
```

row and column names can be set to FALSE with `?write.csv` if desired.

**Data**

```
x <- "DOB
Name
Address


13-03-2003
ABC
xyz.

12-08-2004
dfs
1 infinite loop

01-01-2000
Bob Smith
1234 Main St
Suite 400
"
```

Comment: Data was in a string with \n but when i transfer my text file to string it is removing every \n.

Comment: you mean writing string to the text file?

Comment: Yes @AvinashRaj  i used this command x <- paste(readLines("file.txt")) but it pasted without any \n.